# "бежать по лесу" vs "бежать через лес"

Tags: значения

> бежать **по** лесу
>
> бежать **через** лес

On the surface, they both seem to mean "running through the woods", but I wonder if they are nuanced somehow?

Comment: "Running in woods"  and "running through the woods".

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/988/whats-the-difference-between-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-and-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7/989#989

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nuance is in the purpose

**бежать через лес** - emphasizes the fact that forest is only a landscape feature on your way elsewhere which you're going to cross

**бежать по лесу** - means running in(side) the forest with no connotation of the need to pass through it, it could be for jogging having no destination outside of it and no intention to leave it

Likewise: ехать через поле/по полю, идти через дорогу/по дороге, красться через сад/по саду.

With preposition *через* often verbs with prefix *пере-* are used: пере-плывать/-плыть (через) реку, пере-ходить/-йти (через) дорогу

Comment: Hi. How does "сквозь" compare with these two? I'm not sure if it can be used in this context, though.

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens сквозь is normally used with nouns denoting solid and narrow substances/objects, проходить сквозь стены - pass through walls; пролазить сквозь игольное ушко - squeeze through needle's eye

Answer (score 2):

Смысловые нюансы здесь такие, на мой взгляд:

***бежать по лесу*** можно и без конечной цели, не имея конечного пункта, до которого вы хотите добраться. ***бежать по лесу*** it is possible without the ultimate goal, without having the destination to which you want to get.

***бежать через лес*** подразумевает, что у вас есть конечная цель или пункт, до которого вы стремитесь добраться. ***бежать через лес*** implies that you have an end goal or point that you are aiming to reach.